# Add files parsed with async to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, es6-promise

I need to be able to loop through an array of file paths and filter out files that do not contain a particular string within them. The target array returns an empty array, but instead I want the target array to include the list of files that do not contain the string, with results parsed to remove a substring up to the last instance of the delimiter.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const fileList = ['/L1/L2/file1', '/L1/L2/file2', '/L1/L2/file3', '/L1/L2/file4']
const filterText = 'filter files that contain me'
let targetArray = []

async function parseIncompleteDocumentation() {
  try {
    const delimiter = '/'
    for (let componentFile of coveredComponentsDirectoryList)
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(componentFile, 'utf8', function(err, content) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          } else if (!content.includes(incompleteDocumentationFilter)) {
            resolve(
              existingIncompleteComponentDocumentationList.push(
                componentFile.substring(
                  componentFile.lastIndexOf(delimiter) + 1,
                  componentFile.length
                )
              )
            )
          }
        })
      }
    )
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log('error message', err) // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }
}

const finalArray = await parseFiles()
console.log(finalArray) // returns empty array
```

If `file1` and `file3` contain `filterText`, desired output would be
`['file2', 'file4']`

Comment: Promises and forEach don't mix.  Try replacing with a simple for of.

Comment: You have a bug, foreach wont stop once you resolve.

Comment: @Keith I updated my question with your suggestion, but it's still printing an empty array. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options:

1. Use async/await inside for...of loop.

   ```
   for (let file of fileList) {

     await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, content) => {

            if (err)
              return reject(err);

            //....
            resolve()
         })
     })
   }
   ```
2. Use readFileSync

   ```
   fileList.forEach(file => {

      try{
         let content  = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
         //...
      }
      catch(e) {
         //....
      }
   })
   ```

Comment: Option 2, of course could cause issues.  Current versions of node also come with promisified versions of readFile etc to avoid the Promise constructor.  https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api